# Add a column which stores JSON data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created table like:

```
CREATE TABLE demo
(
    name varchar(50), 
    adress nvarchar
);
```

But I'm not getting how to insert data into `adress` column which stores data of JSON object like:

```
INSERT INTO demo (name, adress) 
VALUES ('vamsi', N'{"city":"avhfb","pin":46374});
```

Like this: The values I get in this `adress` column is dynamic count so that's why I need to store it in JSON format.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `(n)varchar` variables and parameters that you use. The way it's defined right now, your column `adress` is **exactly ONE** character long....

Comment: Though using JSON to store address data in an RDBMS is also a bad idea. Sort each part in its in column.

Comment: You seem to be missing a terminating single quote on your JSON string.

Comment: I'm new to using SQL and address data is just example actually we need to store dynamic data in table means the data which retrieve doesn't have fixed number of columns it always changes so we thinking of it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't overthink it. JSON is still a string, so `nvarchar` will be fine, but add a length to they datatype (probably `nvarchar(max)` for a JSON object).